# Problem with glui

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, header

i was trying out a free code i downloaded from the internet,
when i compiled it says.. 
"Error  2   fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glui32d.lib' MarchingCubesGLUI   MarchingCubesGLUI"

i cant seems to find much reference online about GLui,
i know i dont have glui.h .dll and .lib files etc etc.

so what should/can i do?

FYI: i'm using VS 2008's c++

Answer (score 1):

Please check http://glui.sourceforge.net/.

As it is stated there: "GLUI is a GLUT-based C++ user interface library which provides controls such as buttons, checkboxes, radio buttons, and spinners to OpenGL applications. It is window-system independent, relying on GLUT to handle all system-dependent issues, such as window and mouse management."

So, what you should do IMHO is to download the glui-2.35.zip from the site, unpak it in a directory and build the GLUI executables (dll and lib). See instructions in the readme.txt file included in the donwloaded zip.

The next step would be to make sure that additional include directories contain also the path to include in you glui installation and the lib built previously is included in the project you are trying to compile.

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the needed library (.lib) file, and put it somewhere where the compiler can find it during the linking phase of building your program.

Comment: the problem is i done have one..
not even with the codes downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have openGL installed. I am not sure, but if it is not installed with Visual Studio 2008, you should install it from Platform SDK, downloadable from Microsoft site.

Then, make sure that you have in the list of include directories and of library directories the folders where the header files and lib files for OpenGL are located. (go to Tools/Options, "Projects and Solutions/VC++ Directories" section.